# Determine whether an ee.Image dictionary property has nulls using a mapped function

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have an Earth Engine image collection. Each image has a property that is a dictionary with multiple keys. I want to know if there are any null values in the dictionary.

My idea (code below) is to map a function over the image collection. The function gets the dictionary values and uses JavaScript `indexOf` function to determine if there are null values in the list. I set a new property on the image that is the true/false result.

The problem is that the `indexOf` function requires that the data be client-side (using `getInfo`) and I cannot use client-side values in a mapped function. I get the error:

> A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations

Is there a server-side way to determine whether an ee.Image dictionary property has nulls using a mapped function?

```js
// A mocked up image collection.
var col = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
  ee.Image(0).set('dict', {'key1': 1000, 'key2': 200}),
  ee.Image(1).set('dict', {'key1': null, 'key2': 300})
]);

// A function constructor that returns a function to set a new image property
// that indicates whether an image property dictionary has null values. Provide
// the target dictionary property name to the `dictPropName` parameter.
function getIsNullFun(dictPropName) {
  return function(img) {
    // Get the dictionary values.
    var vals = ee.Dictionary(img.get(dictPropName)).values().getInfo();
    
    // Are there nulls?
    var hasNulls = vals.indexOf(null) !== -1;
    
    // Set an image property the indicates presence of nulls in dictionary.
    return img.set('hasNulls', hasNulls);
  };
}

// Construct the function - define what the dictionary property name is.
var isNullFun = getIsNullFun('dict');

// Map the function over the collection to set the `hasNulls` property per image.
col = col.map(isNullFun);
print('Collection w/ bool prop for "dict has null"', col);



// Do other things with the collection now that you know what images have nulls.
var notNullCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hasNulls', false));
print('Only images WITHOUT null dict values', notNullCol);

var nullCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hasNulls', true));
print('Only images WITH null dict values', nullCol);
```

Comment: Surprisingly, `vals.indexOfSublist([null])` appears to work

Comment: This ^ should be the accepted answer. Would you mind adding it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding one more option here. This one is super simple and short. It produces the number of nulls with `ee.Filter.notNull(['item'])`, `not()`, and `size()`.

```
// A mocked up image with a dictionary property.
var img = ee.Image(1).set('dict', {'key1': null, 'key2': 300, 'key3':null});

// Get a list of values from the dictionary property.
var values = ee.Dictionary(img.get('dict')).values();

// Print out the number of nulls values in the list.    
print(values.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['item']).not()).size());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`ee.List.filter(ee.Filter.notNull)`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list-filter) function to get a list of dictionary values that are not `null` and compare the list length to the length of the comprehensive list of values. Then use the [`ee.Algorithms.If`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-algorithms-if) function to get `true`/`false` for whether the lists are equal or not (contains `null` or not) and then set that value as the new nulls indicator property for the image. You wouldn't have to use `ee.Algorithms.If` if you were satisfied with 0/1 as indicators (the if just gives more flexibility for what is returned).

```js
// A mocked up image collection.
var col = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
  ee.Image(0).set('dict', {'key1': 1000, 'key2': 200}),
  ee.Image(1).set('dict', {'key1': null, 'key2': 300})
]);

// A function constructor that returns a function to set a new image property
// that indicates whether an image property dictionary has null values. Provide
// the target dictionary property name to the `dictPropName` parameter.
function getIsNullFun(dictPropName) {
  return function(img) {
    // Get the dictionary values.
    var vals = ee.Dictionary(img.get(dictPropName)).values();
    
    // Get a list of not null values.
    var notNullVals = vals.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['item']));
    
    // Get the size of values and not null values lists.
    var nVals = vals.size();
    var nNotNullVals = notNullVals.size();
    
    // Compare the list sizes; if not equal, there are nulls.
    var hasNulls = ee.Algorithms.If(nVals.neq(nNotNullVals), true, false);
    
    // Set an image property the indicates presence of nulls in dictionary.
    return img.set('hasNulls', hasNulls);
  };
}

// Construct the function - define what the dictionary property name is.
var isNullFun = getIsNullFun('dict');

// Map the function over the collection to set the `hasNulls` property per image.
col = col.map(isNullFun);
print('Collection w/ bool prop based on dict', col);



// Do other things with the collection now that you know what images have nulls.
var notNullCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hasNulls', false));
print('Only images WITHOUT null dict values', notNullCol);

var nullCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hasNulls', true));
print('Only images WITH null dict values', nullCol);
```

Comment: The code above compares the length of two lists to determine if there are nulls or not. It could be simplified to use the `ee.List.contains()` function, except that the target value is `null`, which the function will not except–the `object` argument needs to be not `null`.

Comment: `ee.Algorithms.If` is used here. Note that it evaluates all arguments (both true and false cases). This can be computationally intensive if your alternatives are large/complex requests. Here, the results are direct boolean assignment, so no concern needed.

Comment: Super helpful thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative to Justin Braaten's answer which uses `ee.Algorithms.IsEqual` to find null values.

```js
// A mocked up image collection.
var col = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
  ee.Image(0).set('dict', {'key1': 1000, 'key2': 200}),
  ee.Image(1).set('dict', {'key1': null, 'key2': 300})
]);


// A function constructor that returns a function to set a new image property
// that indicates whether an image property dictionary has null values. Provide
// the target dictionary property name to the `dictPropName` parameter.
function getIsNullFun(dictPropName) {
  return function(img) {
    // Get the dictionary values.
    var vals = ee.Dictionary(img.get(dictPropName)).values();
    
    var null_test = vals.map(function (value) {
      return ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(value, null);
    });

    var hasNulls = null_test.contains(true);
    
    // Set an image property the indicates presence of nulls in dictionary.
    return img.set('hasNulls', hasNulls);
  };
}

// Construct the function - define what the dictionary property name is.
var isNullFun = getIsNullFun('dict');

// Map the function over the collection to set the `hasNulls` property per image.
col = col.map(isNullFun);
print('Collection w/ bool prop for "dict has null"', col);



// Do other things with the collection now that you know what images have nulls.
var notNullCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hasNulls', false));
print('Only images WITHOUT null dict values', notNullCol);

var nullCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hasNulls', true));
print('Only images WITH null dict values', nullCol);
```

Comment: My answer does not need to know dictionary key names, it just gets a list of all values in the dictionary (`var vals = ee.Dictionary(img.get(dictPropName)).values();`)

Comment: Whoops, missed that

Comment: No worries, thanks for editing. Fun to see all the different ways to do this!